# Why is it so difficult to find the right format for date and time for matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I need to display the time in the x axis using matplotlib, not panda. The y axis should display the temperature. The data has been generated from an api and extracted, before being placed into a multidimensional list. My latest attempt is below. the time is not displayed accurately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import matplotlib

def graph_data():

weather_api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&id='
source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(weather_api)
content = source_code.read()
codes = json.loads(content.decode("utf8"))

#get the data required and put it in an array called 'weather_data'
weather_data=[]

for each in codes['list']:
    weather_data.append([
                         each['dt_txt'],
                         each['weather'][0]['description'],
                         int(each['main']['humidity']),
                         float(each['wind']['speed']),
                         int(each['main']['temp_min']),
                         int(each['main']['temp_max'])])

#store the weather details for each day
day1 = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
forecast_list = []

for each in weather_data:
    date=datetime.strptime(each[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #convert string to date
    if day1.day == date.day:
        d=datetime.strptime(each[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#           time=d.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        forecast_list.append([d, each[4]])

time=[]
temp=[]

for each in forecast_list:
    time.append(each[0])
    temp.append(each[1])
print(time)

plt.plot(time, temp, label = 'Temperature')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.title('Temperature for {0}'.format(day1.strftime('%Y-%d-%d')))
plt.legend()
plt.show()

graph_data()
```

Comment: Define "not displayed accurately".

Comment: displays part of the year and a random number

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code in the question: (1) the indentation is not right, (2) there is some mismatch in opening/closing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You say "displays part of the year and a random number"—probably it is displaying the time accurately, but as a fractional year. What format do you want it to use?

Try using `plt.plot_date` instead of `plt.plot`.

Or, after plotting, you can do

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis_date() # treat the x-axis as dates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) # specify the format you want
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, however the date showing is one hour in the past. Where it should display 03:00 it is displaying 02:00. This is for all the dates

Comment: @Nosh: sounds like the times are in UTC, and you are expecting British Summer Time, or vice versa. Just adjust the times, e.g. in your loop `for each in forecast_list` do `time.append(each[0] + timedelta(hours=1))`.